# Not able to add new directory to my existing project in Heroku

Tags: git

Can't add a new folder to an existing project. In my project I added a new directory to `projects/` but `git add .` is not working. Also tried `git add projects/ .` without success.

```
labanino:pixelandbyte ghostrider$ git add projects/ .
labanino:pixelandbyte ghostrider$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'heroku/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   projects/gcg (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I am able to push to the root of the site but not to `projects/`.

Comment: If the directories are "empty" (no files inside), git won't care about them.

Comment: No, it is not empty.

Comment: if there are files inside those directories and, when adding the directory, git is not "detecting" them, then they are being ignored by git. Check with `git status --ignored`

Comment: Ignored files: .DS_Store

Comment: Hm.... actually, I hadn't noticed the output of your question.... I just assumed a bunch of stuff in my head (sorry fot that). My head is now pointing to EOL conversion. Do you have any kind of EOL conversion set up? It can be a PAIN and I've seen pretty weird stuff happen because of that. I normally switch it off completely.

Comment: @Labanino is `.DS_Store` the only file in that directory? Can you post the output of `ls -la projects` and `git status --ignored projects`?

Comment: Do you have nested Git repositories, e.g. a `.git/` directory in `projects/` or `projects/gcg`?

Comment: @Chris No, I don't, the directory projects is on the root of my site and it has the gcg directory in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but I had a `.git tracking` file in the `projects/` dir. So, I run `rm -rf .git*` and problem fixed.